# using defer in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am having issues using $q.defer in my typescript controller. The error I get is this.$q.defer is not a function. This is my typescript....

```
export class AccountWizardController implements IAccountWizardScope {

  account: Account;

  static $inject = ['$q']
  constructor(private $q: ng.IQService) {
  }

  saveState(): ng.IPromise<Account> {
    console.log(this.$q);
    var deferred = this.$q.defer<Account>();
    console.log(deferred);
    return deferred.promise;
  }
}

export interface IAccountWizardScope {
  account: ContractMonitor.Models.Account;
  saveState(): ng.IPromise<Account>;
}
```

When I call the saveState() method in the view I get the error. This has me completely baffled.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include the rendered JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

`$q` has had `defer` since always ([ref](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/1cdfa3b9601c199ec0b45096b38e26350eca744f)). So my guess is that `this.$q` is `undefined`, and that is the case because you have the wrong `this`. Fix, use a fat arrow to preserve context:

```
saveState = (): ng.IPromise<Account> => {
    console.log(this.$q);
    var deferred = this.$q.defer<Account>();
    console.log(deferred);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: But when I do a console.log on <code>this.$q</code>, I get the Account object back. I tried adding the fat arrow but to no avail. I have changed the signature in the interface to: <code>saveState : () =>  ng.IPromise<ContractMonitor.Models.Account>;</code> but I still get the error.

Comment: `$q` is an `Account` object?

Comment: Yes. in the console I see Object {account:Object} from the console.log

Comment: It seems that after minification the this.$q.defer becomes c.$q.defer. How can I keep t as this after minification.

Comment: How is this error being produced? Is it running in a browser, or are you running a unit test?